# How do you create a hole in an object that is material based?

Tags: materials, normals, normal-map

So I'm working on an object and I want to create holes in it that are material based.

Take a look at the example:

[image: Mesh View]

[image: Rendered View]

This example is from Cyanide227 and I'm referring to the rectangular holes seen on the part of the tire that touches the road.
As you can see, there are no holes in the mesh, it is material driven.

I've been experimenting with baking normals as well as using bump, but I haven't been able to achieve the correct result:

[image: My Attempt]

The plane on the right has a rectangle cut through the mesh, the plane on the left has the baked normal from the other plane. It cannot achieve the depth regardless of the strength you set the normal map to.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: "*As you can see, there are no holes in the mesh, it is material driven.*" Pretty sure those are modeled, you can see the thickness and inner faces. No amount of normal based trickery will add thickness

Comment: Your tire is very high poly, you can just extrud inwards where you are supposed to have a hole?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you both for the replies! Yes I agree. After doing more research into this, I think it must have been modeled. The image Cyanide227 provided of his mesh led me to believe that the holes were material driven and so I wanted to find out if that was possible. Though, it still confuses me why the image he provided of his mesh didn't have the holes haha. Thanks for your time yall!